# Trigger default action after calling e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I trigger the default action *(in this case an a tag click)* after calling `e.preventDefault()`? I tried `$(this).trigger(e)` but it does not work.

```
$(".log-in").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($.cookie("remember")) {
        var account = $.cookie("remember");
        window.location = 'https://' + account + '.mydomain.com';
    } else {
        $(this).trigger(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `e.preventDefault()` inside the if statement

```
$(".log-in").on("click", function(e) {
    if($.cookie("remember")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var account = $.cookie("remember");
        window.location = 'https://' + account + '.mydomain.com';
    } 
});
```